What does `development version` from `do-release-upgrade` mean?
I have a current Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server:
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64)

When I try to do a release upgrade via sudo do-release-upgrade (without -d!) it tells me:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

I already found that the upgrade channel is not open yet, so thats fine.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1511642/872103

But I'm a bit worried that it says development version. I have called do-release-upgrade without the -d option. I don't want to upgrade to a development version.
I've found this question which suggests deleting /etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed.list*:

Unable to disable proposed updates (developer options)

But these files don't exist in my filesystem:
****@****:~$ ls -l /etc/apt
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai 17 09:09 apt.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  8  2022 auth.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 21 10:35 keyrings
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai 17 09:09 preferences.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2445 Nov  1  2023 sources.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2403 Aug 10  2023 sources.list.curtin.old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 21 10:43 sources.list.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 10  2023 trusted.gpg.d
****@****:~$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110 Nov 21 10:43 docker.list

Is this do-release-upgrade message There is no development version of an LTS available. something I need to worry about? If yes, how can I switch to a non-development-version?
Note: I didn't install Ubuntu Server on this system myself. I don't know with which version it was installed, maybe it is already a development version :-/

You can't upgrade directly to 24.04 at the moment. You have to upgrade to 23.10 first (which you can do by following the instructions in the first output you show us), and then upgrade to 24.04. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1512692/158442 (I have done that myself a week ago)

You CAN upgrade at the moment with the -d option, but that is largely untested. If you decide to upgrade now, you're testing the upgrade path, and should thus report any bugs you find to the Ubuntu team. It's generally recommended to wait until the 24.04.1 point release (August) until you upgrade for real.

Also, you're misinterpreting the message about a Development version. You're not on a development version, and you'll not upgrade to a development version now (although you would do that if you had ran -d before 24.04 was released). However I agree the message is not entirely clear.

@ArturMeinild @muru I don't want to upgrade, I just want to know if my current upgrade path via do-release-upgrade would lead into some kind of development version once the the upgrade channel is open. The message indicates this. @ArturMeinild If I understand your latest comment correctly, this is not the case, but the message is misleading. If that is correct, I would ask you to turn the comment into an answer. (Many users do not read comments and I can mark an answer as correct. ;-) ) Thanks!

The -d upgrade option is currently required (22.04 to 24.04) (refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades) but it is not yet a supported upgrade; being still treated as the development options as the current intention is for Quality Assurance testing purposes (it's not supported; and won't be a supported option until after 24.04.1 LTS is released).  As muru has already stated; the only option you have open currently (non-QA/development) is to 23.10 and off the LTS path... which will get you to 24.04 faster; but check its good for your system first!

"I just want to know if my current upgrade path via do-release-upgrade would lead into some kind of development version once the the upgrade channel is open." If used properly, then "No". If misused, then sometimes "Yes".

@muru @ArturMeinild @user68186 @nobody @karel Please reopen, this is not a Dup of 1511903! My question links to 1511602, which is a Dup of 1511903. I answert two times that 1511903 does not answer my question, I wrote it in the comments. I made again and again clear that I not try do update, but to understand the message from do-release-upgrade without -d option. How can a question that asks how to update be a Dup of my question about a command output and explicitly not about how to update?! @ArturMeinild (also in the close voters list) answered my question correctly after a short inquiry.

"If yes, how can I switch to a non-development-version?" which is what the dupe answers, and the rest is answered by ArturMeinild.

@muru and the other: Sorry for the loud comment. It really triggered me at the moment. I should learn not to react in such moments and to calm down.

Normally, when you run sudo do-release-upgrade -d, you'll upgrade to the next development version. For LTS releases, this means upgrading to the next LTS development release, which is available 6 months before the final release.
However, the sudo do-release-upgrade -d changes its meaning after the next LTS is released. Here, you test the upgrade path instead, since the final and tested upgrade path is normally only available after the first point release (which is normally in august).
So to sum up:

From 6 months before up until the next LTS release, sudo do-release-upgrade -d will upgrade to the next development LTS release.
From the LTS is released and up to the first point release (usually 4 months after), sudo do-release-upgrade -d to the next final LTS release, but the upgrade path is untested, and may have errors or fail.

The information you get from the normal sudo do-release-uograde is a way for the developers to tell you that scenario 1 is no longer an option, and that implicitly by running sudo do-release-uograde -d, you will encounter scenario 2.
But I agree this message is not very clear, and much is implied and not explained clearly.

Thanks for the explanation so far! The point is, I do not use the -d option! Nevertheless the message indicates a search for an dev upgrade. So the question is: Is this message just wrong, or is do-release-upgrade trying a dev upgrade do to something else than the command line arguments.

I tried to elaborate.

Your edit made it clear now, thanks a lot!
